# How to decode nested JSON data when you don't know which type of the item would be in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, api, decode

I'm trying to decode JSON data from API call and have some decodable classes to decode JSON but I've got one problem.
In the JSON, there's a single item with same name (let's say "value") but have either string or int depends on "type" of it.

Can someone please help me how can I struct my decodable class in this case? (my example decodable class is below)

```
class ExampleClassToDecode: Decodable {
    let type: String
    let value: String? // this item can be either String or Int in the callback JSON data
}
```

Example JSON

```
0:{
"type":"type1"
"value":"73%"
}
1:{
"type":"type2"
"value":2
}
2:{
"type":"type3"
"value":NULL
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer George, I would never have figured that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an enum with associated values.

Codable conformances:

```
struct Example: Codable {
    let type: String
    let value: Value?
}
```

```
enum Value: Codable {
    case string(String)
    case int(Int)

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()

        if let string = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(string)
            return
        }
        if let int = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
            self = .int(int)
            return
        }

        throw CodableError.failedToDecodeValue
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()

        switch self {
        case .string(let string): try container.encode(string)
        case .int(let int): try container.encode(int)
        }
    }
}
```

```
enum CodableError: Error {
    case failedToDecodeValue
}
```

Usage:

```
let json1 = """
{
    "type": "type1",
    "value": "73%"
}
"""

let json2 = """
{
    "type": "type2",
    "value": 2
}
"""

let json3 = """
{
    "type": "type3",
    "value": null
}
"""
```

```
do {
    let data = Data(json1.utf8) // <- Swap this for other JSONs
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Example.self, from: data)
    print(result)

    switch result.value {
    case .string(let string): print("percentage: \(string)")
    case .int(let int): print("counter: \(int)")
    case nil: print("no value")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```